# How can I log into a firewall first before running fabric commands?

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

I'm trying to get running a deployment file in fabric, but our appservers have a firewall before the actual servers that needs to be logged into first. How can i make fabric log into that first? i haven't been able to find and documentation on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new task and fabric role should do the trick:

```
from fabric.api import run, task
from fabric.decorators import roles
from fabric.state import env

env.roledefs = {"firewall": ["mybox"]}

@roles("firewall")
@task
def do_stuff_on_firewall_server():
    run("some-cmd")
```

You can run this command pretty easily:

`fab do_stuff_on_firewall_server`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you cannot SSH directly into the target server, but you have to SSH into the firewall first, and then from the firewall you can SSH into the target server.

In that case, you can use Fabric's `--gateway` command-line option:

```
$ fab --gateway=firewall.company.com --hosts=server.company.com sometask
```

See https://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.7/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-g

Comment: How would the gateway look in the fabfile? i'd prefer not to have to use the --gateway